# Django manage.py migrate error

Tags: python, django, postgresql

So I am currently in a virtual environment, and when I typed the command line:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and I encounter this problem:

```
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "manage.py", line 24, in <module>
>         execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>       File "C:\Users\DUCNGU~1\Desktop\HAULER~1\api\vnenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
> line 371, in execute_from_command_line
>         utility.execute()
>       File "C:\Users\DUCNGU~1\Desktop\HAULER~1\api\vnenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
> line 317, in execute
>         settings.INSTALLED_APPS
>       File "C:\Users\DUCNGU~1\Desktop\HAULER~1\api\vnenv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py",
> line 56, in __getattr__
>         self._setup(name)
>       File "C:\Users\DUCNGU~1\Desktop\HAULER~1\api\vnenv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py",
> line 43, in _setup
>         self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
>       File "C:\Users\DUCNGU~1\Desktop\HAULER~1\api\vnenv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py",
> line 106, in __init__
>         mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
>       File "C:\Users\DUCNGU~1\Desktop\HAULER~1\api\vnenv\lib\importlib\__init__.py",
> line 126, in import_module
>         return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
>       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>       File "C:\Users\Duc Nguyen\Desktop\HaulerAds\api\settings.py", line 104, in <module>
>         'PORT': int(os.getenv('POSTGRES_PORT')),
>     TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

My current Django version 2.0.3. I checked the python pass and I have the proper path. 
Please help, thank you!

Comment: you're trying to retrieve `POSTGRES_POST`, in the `os.environ` but it's doesn't exists

Comment: The `POSTGRES_PORT` is not defined in your environment.

Comment: try this, `'PORT': int(os.getenv('POSTGRES_PORT', '5432'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to retrieve `POSTGRES_POST`, in the `os.environ` but it doesn't exist.
`int()` can't convert `NoneType`.

If it's possible that the key does not exist in your environment.
you can set a **default value**:

```
'PORT': int(os.getenv('POSTGRES_PORT',5432))
```

The second argument is the **default port** in case that key doesn't exist in `os.environ`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you use PostgreSQL as a database system, but Django has trouble finding the port you use for the PostgreSQL database.

You can set the parameter for the command locally executing the migrations with:

```
POSTGRES_PORT=5432 python manage.py migrate
```

or another port if you configured PostgreSQL in a different way (the default port for a PostgreSQL server is 5432, but you can of course have picked a different one yourself).